# Insert space between two captalized words?

Tags: php, camelcasing

I have two words combined like
`KitnerCoster`
And I want to add a space in the middle, is there any sort of trick anyone knows if separating two words that are both capitalized and that is the only difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you care if the first word is capitalized? If not, do

```
// ASCII
preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', $string)
preg_replace('/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/', '$1 $2', $string)

// Unicode (UTF-8)
preg_replace('/(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})/u', '$1 $2', $string)
```

If you do care, and want to fix `KitnerCostner` but leave `kitnerCostner` alone, then do

```
// ASCII
preg_replace('/\b([A-Z]\S*[a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', $string)
preg_replace('/\b([[:upper:]]\S*[[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/', '$1 $2', $string)

// Unicode (UTF-8)
preg_replace('/\b(\p{Lu}\S*\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})/u', '$1 $2', $string)
```

I've given versions that only match ASCII letters and ones that match [all Unicode characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). The Unicode ones are available in PHP 5.1.0.

Answer (score 4):

Using regular expressions you could do something like

```
s/([a-z])([A-Z])/'$1 $2'/g
```

However my first trial to write a regular expression usually fails so you might have to correct one or the other part.

How do you want to handle a 1-character long word? Like 'X' in FooXBar? The X will not be recognized as a separate word by the above regular expression.

Comment: +1 because I too rarelly write a regular expression which works on the first trial.

Comment: Changing it to a preg_compatible regex (the solution is fine, but the question was about PHP): `preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', $string);`...